# .Net Core Configuration.GetSection().Get<>() not binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm Trying to Inject my settings from appsettings.json into an Object, i'm following microsoft documentation and my Configuration.GetSection().Get<>() is always null, the documentation that i am using is this one [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration)

I am using .Net Core 2.1

My setting is this:

```
{
  "MongoSettings": {
    "ConnectionString": "mongodb://admin:abc123!@localhost",
    "Database": "NotesDb"
  }
}
```

My class to inject is this one:

```
public class MongoSettings
{
    public string ConnectionString;
    public string Database;
}
```

and i'm using the following code to fill my injection and it comes always null.

```
Configuration.GetSection("MongoSettings").Get<MongoSettings>()
```

Below is the return that i am getting when i'm using the code

[image]

My Configuration is ok, look the image below.

[image]

What am i doing wrong to my object comes with ConnectionString and Database null? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your class is 2 fields. The configuration system only works with properties. Add `{ get; set; }` to the end of both of the fields to fix it.

```
public class MongoSettings
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public string Database { get; set; }
}
```